# Как получить значение до и после редактирования (нажатия кнопки клавиатуры) формы?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#DisplayVote').on('keyup', function(e) {
   if ((e.which > 57 || e.which < 48) && e.which !== 8 ) {
      e.preventDefault();
   }
   var endValVote = $(e.target).val();  // Значение после правок
});
```

Данное событие проверяет вводимые данные в форму (пропускает только цифры и бекспейс).

Возможно ли получить значение из редактируемого input до и после правок?

При срабатывании события, сначала создать переменную с тем что было, а потом ещё одну переменную с тем, что стало.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`keyup` - это поздно для пропускания выборочных символов в инпут. Трудно представить, как оно у Вас работает. Что касается старого и нового значений:

```js
$('#DisplayVote').data("oldvalue", $('#DisplayVote').val());
$('#DisplayVote').on('keyup', function(e) {
  if ((e.which > 57 || e.which < 48) && e.which !== 8) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  var oldValue = $(e.target).data("oldvalue");
  var newValue = $(e.target).val();
  console.log("old: ", oldValue, "new: ", newValue);
  $('#DisplayVote').data("oldvalue", newValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="DisplayVote" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#DisplayVote').bind('keyup keydown', function(){

});
```

Answer (score -1):

Вообще есть крайне простой метод localstorage, который будет хранить данные на любой вкладке или даже если браузер перезапустится, пока не перезапишите или удалите значение, а записывать туда будем при нажатие кнопки (т.к. это действие всегда идет перед отпусканием)

```
$('#DisplayVote').on('keydown', function(e) {
localstorage.setItem('displayVote', $('#DisplayVote'));
$('#DisplayVote').on('keyup', function(e) {
if ((e.which > 57 || e.which < 48) && e.which !== 8 ) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
 var startValVote = localStorage.getItem('displayVote')
 var endValVote = $(e.target).val();  // Значение после правок
 })})
```